# Set Location of Visual Studio 2015 Unit Test Projects

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

When I right click a function and click "Create Unit Tests" Visual Studio 2015 decides to create a new Unit Test Project in the root directory of my solution. This means that if I want to create unit tests for all my code, I will end up having dozens of Unit Test Projects in the root of my solution - which makes things messy.

I created a Folder in my Solution called "Tests" and I want all new Test Projects to automatically end up inside this folder. How do I do this? Is it possible to set the location of where Unit Test Projects are created?